# Filter , power bi advance filter

Tags: filter, filtering

I have a filter set on page to show loans of 5-6 categories based on parameter A
I want to add another filter to only one of the categories that has been filtered above

My question is on adding a second filter to only one category of data in the first filter

I had implemented synce slicers